# EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS equivalent in MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, triggers

I am trying to port an Oracle trigger to MySQL. There's an `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS` statement in the trigger and while I have found equivalent statements for everything else, I cannot find one for this. The trigger is something like:

```
IF (yada yada)
    THEN
        BEGIN
            SELECT a
            INTO generic_variable1
            FROM table
            WHERE condition;
            SET generic_variable2 = value1;
     EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS --this part needs to be replaced by valid MySQL syntax
        SET generic_variable2 = value2;
  END;
END IF;
```

How do I convert that part into MySQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should understand that MySQL has a very limited stored proc / trigger language compared to Oracle.  While porting to MySQL, many Oracle users say over and over again, "I can't believe MySQL can't do X!!!!"

The closest thing to EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS may be DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER.

Example (not tested):

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET @generic_variable2 = 1;
```

But you'd declare that *before* the block of code that might throw the exception, not after.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare-handler.html for full docs.

Comment: Bill, thanks for the answer! :) By before, do you mean within the IF statement or even before that? Could you please tell me where to position this? Thanks!

Comment: I believe DECLARE is a statement like any other, so it can go anywhere in a code block or sub-block.  But it's common convention to put DECLARE statements at the beginning of a code block, i.e. right after BEGIN.

Comment: Cool! I'll try it out and let you know. Thank you! :)